# laravel multiple form data submission with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I want to submit multiple input values of a form using ajax. I want to know how to insert those data into a database table in laravel. In my cutomers table i have a email field and it has unique constrain. how can i solve this and save form data to database.

my ajax code:

```js
$("#submit-user-details").click(function() {
  var usertype = $("#user_type_regular").val();

  var firstname = $("#fname").val();
  var lastname = $("#lname").val();
  var phone = $("#phone1").val();
  var email = $("#email1").val();
  var vehicleyear = $("#vyear").val();
  var kilometers = $("#kilometers").val();
  var vehiclemodel = $("#vmodel").val();
  var platenum = $("#platenum1").val();
  var otherinfo = $("#otherinfo").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/store_user_details",
    data: {
      user_type: usertype,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      phone: phone,
      email: email,
      vehicleyear: vehicleyear,
      kilometers: kilometers,
      vehiclemodel: vehiclemodel,
      platenum: platenum,
      otherinfo: otherinfo
    }
  })
    .done(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

my form:

```html
<form class="appform" id="appoinment-form" action="/appointmentUserDetails" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="usertype" id="user_type_regular" value="regular">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="firstname1" placeholder="First name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lastname1" placeholder="Last name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone1" name="phone1" min="10" max="10" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="inputLastname">Vehicle Year</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" name="vehicleYear1" id="vyear">
                            <option selected>Vehicle Year</option>
                        @for ($i = 1990; $i < 2020; $i++)
                            <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option> 
                        @endfor
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="currentKM">(Optional)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Kilometers" name="kilometers" id="kilometers">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="vehiclemodel">Vehicle Model</label>
                        <select class="custom-select" name="vehicleModel1" id="vmodel">
                            <option>Vehicle Model</option>
                            <option>Toyota</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="platenum">Plate Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="platenum1" name="plateNum" min="6" max="6" placeholder="Plate Number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="comment">Any Other Information</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="otherinfo" id="otherinfo"></textarea>
                    <button id="submit-user-details" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

my controller method:

```js
public function storeUserDetails(Request $request)
    {

         $data = $request->all();
         foreach ($request->all() as $id => $value) {
             DB::table('customers')->insert([$id => $value]);
        }
    }
```

help me please.thanks.

Comment: on `$('#submit-user-details').click()` prevent default action.

Comment: Thanks it works. now, how can store those data in database? Can i access each value without looping the arry of data?

Comment: provide your Controller code.

Comment: I edited my problem and add the controller code. i want get each value and insert it to database without looping. can i access like `$request->firstname;`

Comment: @Hashan if you have your model's fillable set. you can just do Customer->fill($request->all()).

Other wise you can just do DB::table('customers')->insert($request->all());

This will work as long as your form field ids are the same name as your columns. otherwise you will need to request->input('field') for each one and put it in the insert

Comment: Thanks a lot. i'll try that out.